# How to make function understand a single integer equals 1

Tags: javascript

I have a function that calculates the total amount of frames from an input on my page. I have it almost finished but the issue is that if I insert an integer like `7` or `83` then I don't know how to make it calculate that and have it know that it's a single frame. I want it to calculate the total amount of frames every time there's user input on that specific input field.

Here's an example of the input and how it works.

```
1-10 will render all frames from 1 to 10, and the total amount of frames is 10.
1-10,2 will render every second frame in the specified range of 1 to 10, and the total amount of frames is 5.
1-4;10-20,2 will render frames 1, 2, 3, 4, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, and the total amount of frames is 10.
1-4;10-20,2;83 will render frames 1, 2, 3, 4, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 83, and the total amount of frames is 11.
7 will render frame number 7 and the total amount of frames will be 1.
83 will render frame number 83 and the total amount of frames will be 1. 

So `;` is like a separator
x - y is from frame x to frame y
x - y , z is every z frame between frame x and frame y
```

```js
            var totFrames = 0;
      
            function check() {
              var input = document.getElementById("id_desiredFrames").value;
              var chunk = input.split(";");
              chunk.forEach(processChunk);
      
              if (totFrames && totFrames !== 0) {
                document.getElementById("TotalFrames").value = totFrames;
                totFrames = 0;
              } else {
                document.getElementById("TotalFrames").setAttribute("type", "hidden");
              }
            }
      
            function processChunk(chunk) {
              var stepInfo = chunk.split(",");
              var step = 1;
              if (stepInfo.length > 1 && stepInfo[1] > 1) step = stepInfo[1];
      
              var range = stepInfo[0].split("-");
              var frame = Math.round((range[1] - range[0] + 1) / step);
              if (frame && frame > 0) {
                totFrames += frame;
              } else {
                totFrames = 0;
              }
            }
```

```html
<input type="text" name="desiredFrames" maxlength="15" placeholder="1-500" onchange="check()" class="Blenderfield" required="" id="id_desiredFrames">
<input type="hidden" id="TotalFrames" name="TotalFrames" value="">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't consider that you can provide just one number like this example: **1-4;10-20,2;83** 83 has no pair. Additionally, you were reseting **totFrame** to 0 when **frame** was <= 0;

```js
            var totFrames = 0;
      
            function check() {
              var input = document.getElementById("id_desiredFrames").value;
              var chunk = input.split(";");
              chunk.forEach(processChunk);
              // Check totFrames
              console.log(totFrames);
      
              if (totFrames && totFrames !== 0) {
                document.getElementById("TotalFrames").value = totFrames;
                // Why do you reset totFrames?
                totFrames = 0;
              }
            }
      
            function processChunk(chunk) {
              var stepInfo = chunk.split(",");
              var step = 1;
              if (stepInfo.length > 1 && stepInfo[1] > 1) step = stepInfo[1];
      
              var range = stepInfo[0].split("-");
              var frame = 0;
              // Check what you're getting here
              if(range.length == 1) {
                  // Only one frame here
                  frame = 1;
              } else {
                  // Maybe you need to check if range[1] is greater than range[0]
                  // Use parseInt to convert values to integer
                  frame = parseInt(range[1]) - parseInt(range[0]);
              }
              if(frame > 0) {
                totFrames += frame;
              // This else resets the counter, you don't need it
              // } else {
              //  totFrames = 0;
              }
            }
```

```html
<input type="text" name="desiredFrames" maxlength="15" placeholder="1-500" onchange="check()" class="Blenderfield" required="" id="id_desiredFrames">
<input type="hidden" id="TotalFrames" name="TotalFrames" value="">
```